# Accessing values in an object resulting of a parsed JSON

Tags: object, powershell-2.0

Have a look to the [following](http://pastebin.com/X0tig4bC) JSON (too big to fit here), I'am not able to get value using

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")
$ser = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$jsonObj = $ser.DeserializeObject($json)

$jsonObj.servers | Where-Object {$_.name -EQ 'Tendaji'} | `
  select-object { $_.ipv4addr }
```

I receive

```
   $_.ipv4Address
    --------------
    113.55.212.113
```

How would I get it to only just return `113.55.212.113`?

Comment: How do you get the $serverDetails ?

Comment: From this: http://pastebin.com/X0tig4bC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to :

```
$_.ipv4Address | get-member
Get-Member -InputObject $_.ipv4Address
```

You may have an array

```
$_.ipv4Address[0]
```

---

Be carreful you've got an error inside your JSON :

```
"name": "Aboubacar""ipv4addr": "143.179.56.126"
```

should be :

```
"name": "Aboubacar",
"ipv4addr": "143.179.56.126"
```

Then

```
$jsonObj.servers[0].ipv4addr
```

gives

```
113.55.212.113
```

So in your code your can use :

```
($jsonObj.servers | Where-Object {$_.name -EQ 'Tendaji'}).ipv4addr
```

Comment: I set `$serverDetails = $jsonObj.servers | Where-Object {$_.name -EQ 'Tendaji'} | `
  select-object { $_.addresses.addr[0].addr }` as seen here http://pastebin.com/X0tig4bC. Not sure how I will integrate it with the code above. Can you please help?